# How to filter TCP packets based on flags using Packet Filter in OpenBSD

Tags: networking, filtering, firewall, flags, openbsd

Well, I didn't know exactly how to ask this question, but I know that you can use the keyword *flags* to especify which flags you want to filter.

According to the documentation of the Packet filter:

> To have PF inspect the TCP flags during evaluation of a rule, the
>   flags keyword is used with the following syntax:
>
> flags check/mask
>   flags any
>
> The mask part tells PF to only inspect the
>   specified flags and the check part specifies which flag(s) must be
>   "on" in the header for a match to occur. Using the any keyword allows
>   any combination of flags to be set in the header.
>
> pass in on fxp0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh flags S/SA
>   pass in on fxp0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh
>
> As flags S/SA is set by
>   default, the above rules are equivalent, Each of these rules passes
>   TCP traffic with the SYN flag set while only looking at the SYN and
>   ACK flags. A packet with the SYN and ECE flags would match the above
>   rules, while a packet with SYN and ACK or just ACK would not.

So, I understood the example and why the packet with the flags S and E can pass (because the E flag is not considered due to the mask SA) and why the packet with only the Ack flag can't pass the firewall.

What I didn't understand is why the packet with the flags S and A can't pass the rule S/SA, if the flag S is "on" in the packet header. Maybe the documentation is ambiguous? Sorry if this is a stupid question or an english misunderstood.

I imagine that it can only pass if it MUST HAS **ONLY** the flag S.
In set arithmetic would be something like this:

**flag(s) must be 'on' in the header** -> **flag(s) pertains to the masked subset** [pf doc]
**only the flag(s) must be 'on' in the header** -> **flag(s) is egual to the masked subset** [what I understood from the example given]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: btw this probably should be migrated to serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

> What I didn't understand is why the packet with the flags S and A can't pass the rule S/SA, if the flag S is "on" in the packet header. Maybe the documentation is ambiguous?

From flags section in pf.conf(5)

> flags (A)/(B) | any
>
> This rule only applies to TCP packets that have the flags (A) set
> out of set (B).

If (B) := SA  and (A) := S -> This rule only applies to TCP packets that have the flags S set out of the set SA.

This means it doesn't have A set.
Paraphrasing a bit:

> This rule only applies to TCP packets that have exactly the flags (A) set out of set (B)

Or as the manual page clarifies later:

> flags S/SA
>
> This is the default setting for stateful connections.
>
> Out of SYN and ACK, exactly SYN may be set

Comment: This is what I was thinking after looking the example @ramrunner . Don't you agree the documentation is ambiguous? It says that the flag(s) in the check part must be 'on' in the header. So the case you pointed when you have S and A, would also match. It doesn't say that only the flag(s) in the check part must match

Comment: Is there a way to pass only SYN and ACK packets, blocking all other?